# Integrate ArcGIS 10 extension INTO ArcEngine 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, .net, visual-studio, extensions

I was wondering if there is a way at all to use some of ArcGIS 10's extension into arc engine.

A good example would be if we could put Arc Hydro extension into ArcEngine.

Answer (score 2):

You are able to access the supporting libaries; but you would need to build the UI all yourself. ArcEngine offers you the ability to create your own run-time apps using ESRI technology; but you have to assemble the general flow yourself.
You also need to make sure you handle the license needs properly with the extensions; yes the ability is there but again the UI and plumbing *(pun-intended for hydro)* needs to be built by you. 
 You can call some of the UI dialogs but building the state and handling the input-output will for sure not be fluid.

Comment: Exactly, Engine can build a new GIS custom with ESRI Library.

Comment: +1 Supposedly it would be possible to implement IApplication and be able to use extensions written for ArcMap; however, I've never heard of a 3rd party app that does this.

Comment: I have worked with tools, written in ArcEgine which are the 3rd Party app; and those would use the API for other extensions like 3D/Spatial for functions; but not a vertical extention like ArcHydro; that really I think may be a stretch.